# HTML, linking a CSS one level up?

Tags: html, css

What I mean is:
From **web/in/in.html** I want to use **css.css** located in **web/css/css.css .**
Is there any way to do it except linking through **http://sdlfjsldfk.it/web/css/css.css?**

**../css/css.css** is not working. I'm stuck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to go one more level up

```
../../css/css.css
```

your first `../` will get you in the map `/in` but the css is one level up so you do a second `../` and then you will be in the right map. Then you just type the path to the css

you could also do the following

```
./css/css.css
```

(`./` should normally link to the root, but not sure about that)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just reference the CSS file in relation to the root? Try using `/css/css.css` this will work from any folder, since the begining `/` means `root`